# How to create new faces for specific keywords on a webmode buffer?

Tags: faces, web-mode, customize-face

## Problem

In a (lsp & web-mode) buffer; "function", "if", "async" are all the same color, I tried to change "if" face with the following:

```
(defface xxx-font-lock-face
  '((t (:foreground "yellow" :weight bold))))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'web-mode
  '(("\\<\\(if\\)" . xxx-font-lock-face)))
```

But this doesn't work.
When I M-x describe-face it describes "web-mode-keyword-face".

I tried diving in the web-mode.el file, defining a new face "web-mode-xxx-face" :

```
(defface web-mode-xxx-face
   '((t (:foreground "red" :weight bold)))
   :group 'web-mode-faces)
```

And then I tried to apply this to the "function" keyword by replacing web-mode-keywords-face at line 2016 in the file where it seemed to bind "function" to "web-mode-keyword-face". But it didn't had any effect and function is still described as "web-mode-keyword-face" in a js file.

---

## Solution

**EDIT**:
As stated by @roomworoof the solution was the following (you need to eval some parts of the code after 'web-mode has loaded like this:)

```
(defvar xxx-mode-js-keywords                                                                                       
  (regexp-opt '("if")))                                                                                           
                                                                                                                  
(defvar xxx-mode-js-font-lock-keywords                                                                             
  (cons (concat "\\([ \t}{(]\\|^\\)\\(" xxx-mode-js-keywords "\\)\\_>") '(2 'xxx-mode-keyword-face)))               
                                                                                                                  
(with-eval-after-load 'web-mode                                                                                   
(add-to-list 'web-mode-javascript-font-lock-keywords xxx-mode-js-font-lock-keywords)                               
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my unskilled code will help.

```lisp
;; new face to separate from original `web-mode-keyword-face`.
(defface my-web-mode-keyword-face
  '((t :inherit font-lock-keyword-face))
  "My face."
  :group 'web-mode-faces)

;; keywords to overwrite with new face.
(defvar my-web-mode-javascript-keywords
  (regexp-opt '("if")))

;; map the keywords to new face.
(defvar my-web-mode-javascript-font-lock-keywords
  (cons (concat "\\([ \t}{(]\\|^\\)\\(" my-web-mode-javascript-keywords "\\)\\_>") '(2 'my-web-mode-keyword-face)))

;; add to `web-mode-javascript-font-lock-keywords`.
(add-to-list 'web-mode-javascript-font-lock-keywords my-web-mode-javascript-font-lock-keywords)
```

Comment: It seems that it suppresses all the fontification of my .js buffers. Every keyword is described as "default" face. Maybe an error in the esoteric part which I never understood (\\([][{[\"[}{}) ?

Comment: My bad, I just had to wrap (add-to-list ...) inside an (with-eval-after-load 'web-mode) block. Thanks a lot for your answer.